# iOS - is it possible to inherit view controller with xib file? and how?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, interface-builder, xib

I have a few view controllers which would have same background image and one or two buttons. Rest of the content would be different for each controller. I would like to create `BaseViewController` which would have `.xib` file and in which I would set background image, buttons and other stuff with constraints. Then I would like create subcontrollers (`HomeViewController`, `GameViewController` and so)  which just inherit from `BaseViewController` and have all stuff set in Interface Builder. Is it possible? And subcontrollers would have set own stuff in Storyboard? Background image set in `.xib` for superclass and tableView in Storyboard for subclass. I know it would be possible when I would set all stuff in code but is it possible with `.xib` and IB?

I was thinking about usage of Container view but it's possible that I would like to change `BaseViewController` and maybe create more supercontrollers so I think if it is possible it would be easier with inheritance.

**Edit:**

Possible way suggested by iphonic. It's based on two controllers that together enabled other controllers to be subclass. BaseGameDesignViewController has .xib file and no more code in controller other than default. Code below is from BaseGameViewController from which inherits other controllers. This has problem with unwind segue which when rolling down has white screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var viewController = BaseGameDesignViewController(nibName: "BaseGameDesignViewController", bundle: nil) as BaseGameDesignViewController
    contentView = viewController.view
    viewController.homeButton.addTarget(self, action: "homeButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.insertSubview(contentView, atIndex: 0)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = self.view.frame
}


func homeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMainSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that xib should be a different xib with other controller say `BaseDesignController`, on BaseViewController, viewDidLoad method, you load the BaseDesignController and add as subview..

Comment: I first try your way iphonic because it's almost what I want. I edited my question. It's working but I have problem with that. When I am going back by unwind segue the screen of controller which is hiding is white. I guess it's because this little hack. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I have one problem with the answer - why to have a controller xib when the only thing you use is it's view? Just create a xib that will contain a view, not a controller!

Comment: You are totally right. When I am doing it this way I could change it to use just custom view instead of controller so I did. But still when I use unwind segue there is white screen instead of background. Is it because views are added by insertSubview and aren't in Storyboard? How can I fix it?

Comment: @LiborZapletal You are getting white screen, may be because you are not setting AutoLayout constraints to the contentView with respect of the parentview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible.

The best solution you can achieve is either based on:

1. Container views

   - having a dedicated view XIB which is then included into every controller
2. Outlets defined in superclass but copy-pasting everything in Interface Builder.

   - you can avoid code duplication but you won't avoid duplication in IB.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to inherit view controllers with .xib files.
However, you can use **Container View** for reusing subviews for your so called child views. You have to create common subviews used in different view controllers in a container view.[Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)